Unable to mount encrypted ZFS filesystem after reboot
Key load error: Failed to open key material file: Input/Output Error.
Command: `mount -o zfsutil -t zfs rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uy913 /root/`.
Message: `zfs_mount_at() failed: encryption key not loaded`.
`zfs_mount_at() failed: encryption key not loaded`.
Mounting `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uy913` on `/root/` failed: Permission denied.
Error: 2.

Failed to mount `rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uy913` on `/root/`.
Please manually mount the filesystem and exit.

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu2) built-in shell (ash).
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs):

Hello everyone, after turning off my machine, when I tried to turn it back on and entered my passphrase, this is what I encountered. Now I'm quite upset because I'm not sure what the issues are.

This is relatively easy to fix, it's happening too frequently:
Use another computer to create a live USB stick with a Linux distribution.
Boot from the live USB.
Open a terminal in the live session and import the ZFS pool without mounting it:
sudo zpool import -N rpool

Load the encryption key:
sudo zfs load-key -a

If you need to specify the dataset explicitly, try:
sudo zfs load-key rpool
sudo zfs load-key rpool/ROOT
sudo zfs load-key rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uy913

Mount the ZFS filesystem:
sudo zfs mount rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uy913

Mount additional necessary filesystems:
sudo mount --rbind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --rbind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --rbind /sys /mnt/sys

Chroot into your system:
sudo chroot /mnt

Check and fix potential issues:
zpool status rpool

Exit chroot and reboot:
exit
sudo reboot

The computer should reboot normally now.

Thanks enough.I tried. But at the second line, sudo zfs load-key rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uy913, the output was "key load error: keys must be loaded for encryption root of 'rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_uy913' (rpool)"

I modified the answer

Hello
I encountered a problem while using the command sudo zfs load-key -a. The output was:
Key load error: Failed to open key material file: No such file or directory
0 / 1 key(s) successfully loaded

Additionally, when I tried the command sudo zfs load-key rpool, I received the following output:
Key load error: Failed to open key material file: No such file or directory
``

The key material file cannot be found. This could be due to several reasons: the file path is incorrect, the file does not exist, or there are permission issues. Make sure you know the correct location of the key material file.
If it's on another drive or partition, mount that first where it resides mount /dev/sdXY /mnt ; if you don't know where it is find / -name "your-key-file"; Use the correct path when loading the key. For example: bzfs load-key -a -o keylocation=file:///mnt/path-to-your-key-file; check the ZFS configuration, the encryption keys must be properly configured.

link
Here  I explained what I got

the ouput is invalid option o
I used the option L by typingzfs load-key -a  -L keylocation=rpool/keystore, but I got `alternate keylocation may only be 'prompt' with -r or -a
usage:
load-key [-rn] [-L ] <-a | filesystem|volume>
For the property list, run: zfs set|get
For the delegated permission list, run: zfs allow|unallow`
so isnt work

Same here, did you find a solution?
